# Why does VarType() return vbString for DOM objects?

Tags: dom, vbscript

I'm attempting to write a VBScript function embeded in an HTML page to apply CSS style changes to multiple items at once. I wanted the function to accept a variant array where the elements can be a mixture of either:

1. A string representing an HTML 'id' attribute
2. An object returned by a call to document.getElementById()

Initially, in order to parse the elements of the array, I tried using VarType() to check if the item was a vbString or a vbObject and, if it was the former, call document.getElementById() to convert the id string into an object for further manipulation.

I was extremely surprised to discover that VarType() would *always* return vbString when passed a DOM object returned from a getElementById() call. I had to switch to using TypeName() instead, as it was able to differentiate between an actual String and a DOM object.

Calling VarType() with other non-DOM objects returns vbObject, as expected, so why does it think DOM objects are strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bold part is where you are:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/3kfz157h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx
>
> The VarType function never returns the value for Array by itself. It
>   is always added to some other value to indicate an array of a
>   particular type. The value for Variant is only returned when it has
>   been added to the value for Array to indicate that the argument to the
>   VarType function is an array. For example, the value returned for an
>   array of integers is calculated as 2 + 8192, or 8194. **If an object
>   has a default property, VarType (object) returns the type of its
>   default property.**

Here's a test:

```
Class ObjWithDefaultProperty
    Public Default Property Get Self
        Self = "string"
    End Property
End Class

Class ObjWithoutDefaultProperty

End Class

Dim with_default
Set with_default = New ObjWithDefaultProperty

Dim with_no_default
Set with_no_default = New ObjWithoutDefaultProperty

MsgBox VarType(with_default) 'Returns vbString
MsgBox VarType(with_no_default) 'Returns vbObject
```

And a workaround:

```
Function VarTypeEx(var)
    If IsObject(var) Then
        VarTypeEx = vbObject
    Else
        VarTypeEx = VarType(var)
    End If
End Function
```